# what does .[dev] mean in pip install -e .[dev]

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to follow local setup for contributing to flask. [Here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst#contributing-testsuite) is the link to contribution guide. Here, i am confused with what the following line does

```
pip install -e ".[dev]"
```

it mentioned that it install's flask in editable mode with development dependencies. so, this  will show changes made in the code immediately in the local python version.(Please correct me if i am wrong). What i don't understand is `".[dev]"` . What does this mean? does dev has special behaviour here or i can use anything like ".[hello]" .

Comment: `".[dev]"` adds the optional installs [for `dev`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/d5665e4ba6cf4f7eabdc0be047952a27965a455f/setup.py#L44). See #6 in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples. `-e` means editable mode. Hence the description *"Install Flask in editable mode with development dependencies"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, can you help me with how this works?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"how this works"*?

Comment: @InAFlash,  ...as the documentation jonrsharpe linked indicates, you can use `[hello]` *if* the package you're installing were written to have that name be meaningful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+what+do+mean+in+%22pip+install%22